# can I estimate a time varying seasonal effect in R with GAMM?

Tags: r, time-series, gam, cyclic, stl-decomposition

I would like to use a generalized additive model to investigate time-series data in R.  My data are monthly and I would like to estimate a seasonal effect and a longer run trend effect. I have followed some helpful posts by Gavin Simpson [here](http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2014/05/09/modelling-seasonal-data-with-gam/) and [here](http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2011/06/12/additive-modelling-and-the-hadcrut3v-global-mean-temperature-series/):

My data look like this:

[image: trips]

I have the full data set available on my github [page](https://github.com/aaronmams/cool-time-series-stuff/blob/master/data/trips.csv):

I have attempted to specify a generalized additive model with smooth seasonal and trend terms as follows:

```
    df <- read.csv('trips.csv')
    head(df)
    # A tibble: 276 × 2
     date ntrips
   <date>  <int>
    1  1994-01-01    157
    2  1994-02-01    169
    3  1994-03-01    195
    4  1994-04-01    124
    5  1994-05-01    169

    #add a time column
    trips <- tbl_df(trips) %>% mutate(time=as.numeric(date))

    mod1 <- gamm(ntrips~s(month,bs="cc",k=12) + s(time),data=trips)
```

I extracted the estimate of the seasonal effect as follows:

```
    pred <- predict(mod1$gam,newdata=trips,type="terms")
    seas <- data.frame(s=pred[,1],date=trips$date)
    ggplot(seas,aes(x=date,y=s)) + geom_line()
```

This plot is included below:

[image: gam seasonals]

My question is: in the original data the seasonal peaks move around a little from year to year.  In the embarassingly simple GAM I have specified the seasonal effect is constant.  Is there a way to accommodate time varying seasonality with a GAM?

I have analyzed [these](https://search.proquest.com/openview/cc5001e8a0978a6c029ae9a41af00f21/1?pq-origsite=gscholar&cbl=105444) data using the STL approach of Cleveland et al.:

Using the STL paradigm, how wiggly or smooth one allows the seasonal effects to be seems to be a matter of preference or choice.  I would prefer if I could allow the data to tell me the difference between random error and a shifting seasonal peak.  GAMS seem better suited to this goal as they lend themselves more readily to statistical model fitting-type exercises...but I would like to know if there is a parameter in the R package for fitting gams that allows time varying seasonal effects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is: yes, a GAM model can be formulated for the question you are interested in. If we assume that the trend and seasonal components of the model interact smoothly we have a the smooth equivalent of a continuous-continuous interaction. Such interaction can be fitted in a GAM using a tensor product of the two marginal smooths:

1. the seasonal cyclic smooth, and
2. the longer-term trend smooth

Incidentally, I have further blog posts on these:

- https://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2015/11/21/climate-change-and-spline-interactions/ and
- https://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2015/11/23/are-some-seasons-warming-more-than-others/

Read those for more detail, but the essential aspects are to fit the following model:

```
## fix the knots are just passed the ends of the month numbers
## this allows Dec and Jan to have their own estimates
knots <- list(month = c(0.5, 12.5))

## original model, fixed seasonal component
m1 <- gam(ntrips ~ s(month, bs="cc", k=12) + s(time), data = trips,
          knots = knots)

## modified model with
m2a <- gam(ntrips ~ te(month, time, bs = c("cc","tp"), k = c(12, 10)), data = trips,
          knots = knots))
```

An alternative to the second model is an ANOVA-like decomposition of the two main effects plus interaction. In the modified model above, all three components are bound up in the single tensor product smooth, the `te()` part of the model.

The ANOVA-like decomposition variant would be fitted using

```
m2b <- gam(ntrips ~ ti(month, bs = 'cc', k = 12) +
             ti(time, bs = 'tp', k = 10) +
             ti(month, time, bs = c("cc","tp")), data = trips,
           knots = knots)
```

The third `ti()` then is the smooth interaction, separated from the main smooth effects of the seasonal and long-term trend.

I've shown these fitted using `gam()` but they can be used with `gamm()` also if you need to include an ARMA process for the model residuals.